# How to find the inverse involving 2 variables

Tags: functions

I am trying to solve  this using what I have read from this site but I always hit a dead end.
Consider the function $$f: \mathbb R \times \mathbb R \to \mathbb R\times\mathbb R$$ defined by $$f(x,y) = (x+y, x-y)$$ Show that the inverse is 
$$f^{-1}(a,b) = \left(\frac{a+b}2, \frac{a-b}2\right),\forall (a,b)\in\mathbb R \times\mathbb R$$.

Comment: So what happens when you are given $x, y$ and you plug them in to the function $f\circ f^{-1}(x,y)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If
$x+y=a,x-y=b$ then $x=\frac{a+b}{2},y=\frac{a-b}{2}$ and $$f\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a-b}{2}\right)=(a,b)$$
$$f^{-1}\left(f\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a-b}{2}\right)\right)=f^{-1}(a,b)$$
$$f^{-1}(a,b)=\left(\frac{a+b}{2},\frac{a-b}{2}\right)$$
because $$f\left(f^{-1}(a,b)\right)=(a,b)$$

Comment: Thanks! for the response and the editing. It's clearer now.